# How to stack multiple objects into a shape of another one?

Tags: modeling

is there possibly a addon or a modifier that allows you to stack multiple objects into a shape of another?, if you do not understand what i am saying here is a example of what i want : 
[image: As you can see i have a little sphere and a big cube]

Then you apply the modifier/addon, and [this](https://giphy.com/gifs/3ohhwfrrmViXl6sftu) would be the result.
Please help,
Thank you :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Final result:

[image: final]

### Overview:

You can use **Particle System** for such task. In my example you can see Suzanne and Cube filled with Spheres and Cube filled with Suzannes.

### Particle System setup:

First add **Particle System** to your object - the one that is volume/shape/emitter.

Setup it as in the picture below:

[image: setup]

- **Start/End** should be set to 0, so particles will be generated at one time,
- **Emit** from **Faces** > **Grid** will assure that particles will be distributed evenly,
- **Resulotion** - how many particles should be in the emitter,
- **Render** > **Object** is an object you want to distribute,
- **Size** is a size of this object.

Set this settings in **Wireframe mode** to see changes. After everything is as it should be, you can go to **Modifiers** tab and **Convert** Particle System to mesh. Then delete/hide your emitter object.

[image: convert]

### Edit:

Difference with high resolution between **Emit from Faces** and **Volume**:

[image: fv]

### Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time :D, but i have a question, is there a way to specify number of object (for example to have the same number of spheres on a cube, also same number on Suzanne). The reason why i need this is for shape keys. Thanks!

Comment: @Sinci1 I don't think this is possible. You can use Emit from Verts and then set number of particles but otherwise (Emit from Face/Volume) you have control only upon Resolution value and I honestly don't know how it is calculated. https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/physics/particles/emitter/emission.html From here it means that it's Grid > Resolution and Grid is probably calculated from mesh surface. Also Volume Grid has a bug: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71612/why-are-particles-are-missing-when-using-volume-grid-emission

Comment: Bummer, guess i will have to count manually, thanks anyway :D , also another mini question, is it at least possible to see how many particles there are before converting?. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sinci1 In Particle System tab, Render section choose Halo and under Display section check Number.